# sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist"); Run Time Error

Tags: java, android, jar, sip

I Develop Sip App for Android Client and Server in Java but when I Run Android app.
I Have Error in

```
sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist");
```

> Run Time Error Message :- 11-11 07:39:45.816: E/AndroidRuntime(510):
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.sip.SipFactory.setPathName

also in Java was this Error but when I Add **log4j-1.2.17.jar file** it Solve but the same Error in Android and I Add **log4j-1.2.17.jar File** but it's Not Work ....

Can anyone Help Me?

Comment: Is the error something at run time, or a compile-time error? What's the error message?

Comment: Run Time Error Message :- 11-11 07:39:45.816: E/AndroidRuntime(510): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.sip.SipFactory.setPathName

Answer (score 0):

in android you should add log4j in libs folder. adding jar in build file would not work. if project does not contain libs folder then create a libs folder in project and put your jar in there. then by right click over the jar -> build path-> add to build path. it should works. another thing in android you may face core javax error. see below link for that 
[Jain SIP stack on android complains of mistaken use of core class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335248/jain-sip-stack-on-android-complains-of-mistaken-use-of-core-class)

Comment: is there any other solution ?