# Jain SIP stack on android complains of mistaken use of core class

Tags: android, sip, jain-sip

I'm trying to implement the JAIN sip stack on android, but when I try to compile the demo program i get this error:

```
trouble processing "javax/sip/ClientTransaction.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2012-11-11 22:27:28 - Jain-Test-and] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-11-11 22:27:28 - Jain-Test-and] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Is it possible to add the --core-library argument to the compiler in eclipse, and if so, how do I do this, I can add command line options to the program, but can't figure out how to do it to the compiler.  Also, is this advised, or is there another way around this?

Answer (score 3):

The JAIN jars are using the `javax` namespace for their packages. Android doesn't allow to use core libraries in an external jar. So you have repackage them. You can do this in combination with [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [JarJar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/wiki/GettingStarted) (as mentioned in the error output) by accomplish following steps:

- [Install Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html)
- [Follow this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages)

Add this code in the build.xml for repackaging the JAIN jars:

```
<target name="-jarjar" depends="compile">
    <taskdef 
        name="jarjar" 
        classname="com.tonicsystems.jarjar.JarJarTask"
        classpath="buildtools/jarjar-1.4.jar"/>

    <jarjar jarfile="${out.absolute.dir}/jain-sip-sdp-repackaged.jar">
        <fileset dir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}" />
        <zipfileset src="libs/jain-sip-sdp-1.2.2014.jar" />
        <rule pattern="javax.**" result="com.demo.@1"/>
        <rule pattern="gov.nist.javax.**" result="com.demo.@1"/>
    </jarjar>

    <jarjar jarfile="${out.absolute.dir}/jain-sip-api-repackaged.jar">
        <fileset dir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}" />
        <zipfileset src="libs/jain-sip-api-1.2.jar" />
        <rule pattern="javax.**" result="com.demo.@1"/>
    </jarjar>

    <jarjar jarfile="${out.absolute.dir}/jain-sip-ri-repackaged.jar">
        <fileset dir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}" />
        <zipfileset src="libs/jain-sip-ri-1.2.2014.jar" />
        <rule pattern="gov.nist.javax.**" result="com.demo.@1"/>
    </jarjar>

</target>
```

Call `ant install` in your command line tool. Add the new jars to your build-path and delete the old jars.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a supported Android port of JAIN SIP by the team who wrote much of the original JAIN SIP stack:

http://www.telestax.com/jain-sip-stack-for-android/